# Constant, juvenile conflicts with colleague after promotion turmoil

Tags: software-industry, management, promotion, politics, conflict-resolution

I am Software Architect at my current company. I was offered the role of team manager when my manager (who I’ll call Bill) was promoted 6 months ago. I told Bill that I would probably provide greater value in an engineering role and was probably due for an engineering promotion anyway. Bill agreed and said that the manager role would then go to a very junior engineer (who I’ll call Junior) who had shown interested manager duties. I agreed that this seemed logical.

Bill offered Junior the manager role and Junior was extremely upset. Junior had been expecting an engineering promotion and was unhappy to learn that the engineering promotion was being offered to me. Bill discussed this with me and we both agreed that Junior wasn’t ready to lead the team.

Months go by and no one has applied for the manager job. Junior had been filling in and finally asked to have the manager position in an official capacity. Junior’s request is approved. I arrange to report to Bill so that I can avoid retaliation from Junior.

Almost immediately, Junior starts trying to interfere in a big project that I’m running with a team of contractors- trying to act as if he’s running the project, falsely taking credit for my work, insinuating to others that he’s my supervisor. I raise these issues with Bill. Every time Bill councils Junior on the bad behavior, it returns in a slightly modified form. When I address these things with Junior, I get a lot of excuses and no accountability.  Junior acts as if we are in some type of extreme competition.

So today I had my weekly meeting with Bill. I tell him how bad things are getting. Bill suggests that Junior and I meet with Bill simultaneously and talk out our differences.

I don’t mind doing this, but I dont think it will work. Junior will likely just deny his bad behavior and attempt to paint me as delusional and insecure. Bill wants me to help level up Junior, but Junior thinks its all a big competition. What should I do here?

Comment: It's best if you follow the directions of Bill. Even if you suspect the meeting will go nowhere, you should still have it, as it helps decide what the next steps are.

Answer (score 2):

Acting is almost always better than speculating.

I'd suggest a two-part action:

1. **Things that are not expected:**

   Start documenting the problems. Do not, I repeat, **do not** point out the person, rather concentrate on the actions and the problems / issues they create. Once you have a proper list of actions that you want to avoid (or not to happen, in first place), go to the joint meeting and discuss them out. Once the junior agrees, note down them as MoM and circulate after the discussion, including Bill.
2. **Things that are expected:**

   Also, have a list of items mentioning how you'd want / expect things to be. It's not practically possible to cover all the scenarios, but based on your prior experience, list down some of the major cases and how you'd expect them to turn out. Again, discuss the same in the meeting and come to an agreement, circulate it.

After that, follow up on the situation. In case the junior tries to interfere again in a not-so-constructive way, append the documentation and ask for help from Bill. They should be able to take it up from there.

Comment: The only problem in this advice is tha from purely psychological point of view is extrenly unpleasant. I dont give a f....k aproach here may lead to better outcome.